# Want to show value of slider in textblock?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm making a windows phone 7 app and i put in a slider. It starts at 1 and ends at 80. I want to have it so when you stop the slider it shows the value of wherever the slider is in a textblock. (like if someone stops halfway, a textblock would say 40)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest would be to Bind the sliders value property to your Textblocks Text property and then you would get the value updated every time it gets changed. You could create a converter too because the Sliders Value is a double, and then with the converter you could convert this value to Int too.

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=YourSlider,Path=Value}"
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. If the decimal numbers annoy you then create a converter than will round the number.

Comment: @Kasper: I think Binding.StringFormat will be better than converter here.

Comment: @alpha-mouse Never used Binding.StringFormat, but if it works then it is great and even easier then a converter. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just set the TextBlock.Text with the Slider.Value.ToString() in the event fired after you stopped dragging/changing the slider.

If you want, you can also shorten the value with Math.Round():

```
TextBlock.Text = Math.Round(Slider.Value, [Number of Decimals]).ToString()
```

Regards
Chris

Comment: This is not a particular good solution. It does not take advantage of the binding functionality offered by XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an valuechanged event for the slider (something like this)

```
private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{

}
```

Then in that event, you can set the text of the textbox ->

```
textbox1.Text = silder1.Value.ToString();
```

Everytime the slider changes, the event fires, so the textbox changes aswell

hope this helps,

bart

Comment: hey thanks a lot man, but i get the error "NullReferenceException was unhandled". Any idea what to do? thanks,

Comment: Can you post a piece of your code, where you do the things mentioned above?

Comment: `private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            slidertext.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();



        }`

Comment: slidertext.Text = slider1.Value.ToString();

Comment: You should also look into the answer given by BigL, Because that answer is practicly better than my own. Because it makes use of the binding system. If you want to continue with my answer, i suggest you do a Debug.Writeline(slider1.Value.ToString()) to see if that produces the value you have in your slider.

Comment: I too have NullReferenceException was unhandled, what I can do? BigL answer isn't ok for me because I need to do some calculations on the value before showing it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Bart Teunissen' answer is pretty good but just add a simple check either OldValue is available or not, then it will work perfect.

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
   if(slider.OldValue != null)
   {
      textbox1.Text = silder1.Value.ToString();
   }
}
```

hope this help.